# Load more when the top is reached

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

As we can use load more functionality when `onEndReached`, the same way how can we use load more when we reach to the top of the list ?
Also while doing this when I load more data at the top, Flat list moves to the very top element and hence scroll becomes infinite.

thanks.

Comment: did you try with the `onRefresh` property of the `Flatlist` component? Check this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pHLFJs7jlI4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, we can achieve this in React native 0.60 and above, since the significant changes been made in the Virtual list. Still its doesn't contain the solution for Android.

Answer (score 8):

**1)** You can use onScroll callback and get offset from top from event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y

0 means the top point

For example:

```
<FlatList
    data={messages}
    onScroll={
        (event: NativeSyntheticEvent<NativeScrollEvent>) => 
            onContentOffsetChanged(event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y)
    }
/>

onContentOffsetChanged = (distanceFromTop: number) => {
    distanceFromTop === 0 && makeSomething();
}
```

**2)** Or you can use "inverted" property and onEndReached will call at top of the screen

> inverted
>   Reverses the direction of scroll. Uses scale transforms of -1.

Comment: thanks for the reply, but I'm facing an issue with the same implementation as you described above, Is that once I load more data and render is called the flat list move back to the latest top element, it's not as smooth as the natural scroll (adding data at bottom). like we load more in bottom the focus stays on the current item but in case of top, it flickers on the very top.

Comment: How do you add new items to list? Do you just add them to the end? Because you need to just add new items at the end of your list

Comment: Since i require new loaded data on top of my existing data, I simply append my old data to newly fetch data, so in the array it becomes my top level data, for example I have **[1,3,4,5,6]** in the state list and i receive **[a,b,c,d]** from my server, I simply append my old data in it and hence list becomes **[a,b,c,d,1,3,4,5,6]**
once I add this, my flat list scrolls to top and focuses on **a** , this behaviour is the major issue.

Comment: Can you try to use invert property and add new data to the end?

Comment: I have a similar issue, so the amount of items in memory increase infinitely as I append more. Infinite scrolling has it [usability and performance disadvantages](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/infinite-scrolling-tips/) so I'm considering other alternatives

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it by `inverted` prop. When you `FlatList` is inverted your `onEndReached` would be called when you reach the top.

Comment: Yes, thats doable but what I required was load more at both end, with react native 60.1 we can do this, but still not very much stable though.