# how to call a function after scrolling to top in react native flatlist

Tags: react-native

function MyComponent() {
    const flatListRef = React.useRef()

```
const toTop = () => {
    // use current
    flatListRef.current.scrollToOffset({ animated: true, offset: 0 })
}

return (    
    <FlatList
        ref={flatListRef}
        data={...}
        ...
    />
)
```

}

Comment: I think this is related to https://stackoverflow.com/a/54928134/10278150

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

[onScrollToTop](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview#onscrolltotop) function

Comment: isn't `onScrollToTop` for `ScrollView` and not `FlatList`

Comment: @GáüřãvJõşhï https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist#props

Answer (score 1):

You can use onRefresh function like billow

```
<FlatList
    ref={flatListRef}
    data={...}
    onRefresh={yourFunction}
 />
```

get more about flatlist read the [doc](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist)