# React Native FlatList OnScrollToTop only fires once

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I am creating a project where I need to know when the user scrolls to the top of the flatList

my code is

```
<FlatList
                  keyExtractor={item => item.id}
                  data={this.state.data}
                  onScrollToTop={console.log('hey')}
                  renderItem={({ item }) => //blah blah render
/>
```

terminal only fires `hey` once

Comment: Can you elaborate on how do you scroll to top? or how do you expect from the user to scroll to top?

Comment: I expect the user to scroll the top. It starts at the top but I want it so that the code can execute every time a user scrolls to the top

Comment: This ans will resolve your issue [to check flatlist reached to top](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54928134/9756445) basically onScroll feature returns an event where you can check and get offset from top from event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y

Answer (score 0):

The docs days:

> Fires when the scroll view scrolls to top after the status bar has been tapped.

2 things:

- It's iOS only
- It's when the user tap the status bar (it's more or less a hidden feature)

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview#onscrolltotop